# How can I make PHPUnit ignore a file pattern?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, phpunit

I'm doing Code Coverage reports for a project and there's a ton of files that are included or required while tests are running that are not actually required to be tested or added to coverage reports (I'm using Zend Framework 2; config + Module files are the culprit here).

Is there an *easy* way to simply ignore the file pattern `modules/*/Module.php`?

This is my blacklist:

```
<filter>
    <blacklist>
        <directory>config</directory>
        <directory>vendor</directory>
        <directory>module/*/config</directory>
    </blacklist>
</filter>
```

However, adding `<file>module/*/Module.php</file>` has no effect on html code coverage reports; adding it has no effect whatsoever on including `Module.php` files in the coverage reports.

Zend Framework is booted up in the phpunit `bootstrap.php` file with the usual

```
Application::init(require "config/application.test.php")
```

Short of adding the `Module.php` file for every single module to the blacklist, is there any way PHPUnit can actually do this correctly? I'm not looking for answers that use the `setUp` method in PHPUnit's test cases; I'm looking for a configuration.

I'm using PHPUnit 4.7 + 4.8.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, in order to exclude multiple files with the same name, `<file>` normally wont do a thing as it will only match a single file exactly.

The solution is to use `<directory>`, but to use the suffix attribute;

```
<phpunit
    bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
    colors="true"
    convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Test Suite">
            <!-- functional tests -->
            <directory>tests</directory>
            <!-- unit tests -->
            <directory>module/*/test</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <!-- ignore folders for code coverage -->
    <filter>
        <blacklist>
            <directory>config</directory>
            <directory>vendor</directory>
            <directory>module/*/config</directory>
            <directory suffix="Module.php">module/*</directory>
        </blacklist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

`<directory suffix="Module.php">module/*</directory>` will match multiple files that end in `Module.php` within the top level of the module's directory, including `Module.php` itself.

Since there's no reason for any other php file to be in that directory in Zend Framework 2, it seems to be the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 3):

Where did u add your file tag ?

This is my `blacklist` tag it's working for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit
    bootstrap="Bootstrap.php"
    colors="true"
    stopOnError="true"
    stopOnFailure="false"
    strict="true"
    verbose="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="All Modules">
            <directory>../module/*/tests/*Test</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
   <filter>
        <blacklist>
            <directory suffix=".php">../vendor</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">../config</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">../data</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">../module/*/src/*/Controller</directory>
            <file>../module/*/Module.php</file>
            <file>../module/*/src/*/Factory/*ControllerFactory.php</file>
            <directory suffix=".php">../module/*/tests/*</directory>
        </blacklist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <ini name="memory_limit" value="2047M" />
    </php>
    <logging>
      <log type="coverage-html" target="../build/tests/coverage/" charset="UTF-8"
           yui="true" highlight="false"
           lowUpperBound="35" highLowerBound="70"/>
      <log type="coverage-clover" target="../build/tests/clover.xml"/>
      <log type="junit" target="../build/tests/junit.xml" logIncompleteSkipped="false"/>
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

I have this structure :

```
- module
- vendor
- tests
  - phpunit.xml
- public
- build.xml
```

Comment: I added my `<file>` tag inside of the blacklist, same as you, but Module files still show up in the coverage reports. I'll do a little more testing.

Comment: I use Zend Framework 2 with Jenkins, and PHPunit. i updtae my post to show you the complete phpunit.xml file

Comment: I use ZF2, Bamboo and PHPUnit :) - Everything but coverage (`--coverage-html`) works completely fine; the modules are loaded when `Application` is bootstrapped. The frontend is tested via behat/QA, and the only reason zf2 is even booted up is because someone put functional tests in with unit tests

Comment: Ok, I can't help you more than I did, here I think it's not your file config fault, maybe Bamboo have config to exclude files in it's code coverage render ?

Comment: Actually, I figured it out, but you did point me in the right direction - you can use the `suffix=""` attribute on `<directory>` to exclude the module file. Thanks~